# Can we use Firebase update function for updating priority as well

Tags: firebase

I am updating some properties of my object in firebase using the update method. As part of the update call, can i also update the priority of my object?

I have a collection of objects stored in firebase. I am using the Javascript sdk to interact with my data. Whenever i update any property of an object, i set the priority of the object to Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP constant.

Now, i want to start storing the priority of each object in a property called UpdatedOnTimestampTs defined on the object. Whenever i update any property i will also update UpdatedOnTimestampTs with TIMESTAMP constant.

Now the problem is, I am unable to find a way to call the update function along with priority (no updateWithPriority like setWithPriority). So if I update the UpdatedOnTimestampTs and priority in two different operations using the TIMESTAMP constant i may (or will) end up with a different values.

How can i address this?

Comment: What's the purpose of duplicating the priority in the data? Any reason you don't simply use getPriority() on the returned data instead? Understanding the details of your use case here will help provide a concise answer

Comment: For two reasons - 1. Firebase forge does not display priority and we want to know that value. and 2. We use REST APIs in our c# based middle tier to pull data down and again, we do not see priority in the data pulled down.

Comment: You can add "format=export" as a query parameter to your REST calls to export priority data.  Unfortunately there is no updateWithPriority function in Firebase yet.

Comment: @Kato, say you need to set the timestamp as a priority so that then you can query for results between two dates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know I'm way late on an answer here, but I'm just coming across the need for something similar now and `updateWithPriority` doesn't exist (nor a way to easily view/edit priorities in the Forge).

You can include the specially-named key, `.priority` in your update and it ought to achieve the desired effect.

The `.priority` key is documented in the [Firebase REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-priorities), but can be used in the other libraries.

So, in Javascript, the following would work if you only wanted to update the priority (which, there is `setPriority` for that):

```
var fb = new Firebase("http://a_firebase.firebaseio.com");
var ref = fb.child("/path/to/child");
var data = { ".priority": (new Date()).getTime() } //timestamp, as you mentioned
ref.update(data);
```

If you wanted to change the priority while you're updating other properties, which is what you had asked, just include it with the data you want to update:

```
var fb = new Firebase("http://a_firebase.firebaseio.com");
var ref = fb.child("/path/to/child");
var data = { 
    "property1": "updated_val",
    "property2": "updated_val2",
    ".priority": (new Date()).getTime(), //timestamp, as you mentioned
}
ref.update(data);
```

**EDIT:** To be clear, this will update the priority *at the location of the child reference* (i.e. `/path/to/child`) not the priorities of the individual children that are being updated (i.e. priorities of `property1` and `property2`). If you wanted to include a priority for the children that are being updated, and the children are leaf nodes (i.e. string, number, boolean), then you can use the specially-named `.value` key in conjunction with the `.priority` key to do so.

The following example shows how to update the priority for the root location that the update is occurring from (i.e. `path/to/child`) as well as for both the children that are being update (i.e. `property1` and `property2`). Obviously, you could selectively pick which priorities to update if you didn't want to update them all.

```
var fb = new Firebase("http://a_firebase.firebaseio.com");
var ref = fb.child("/path/to/child");
var newPriority = (new Date()).getTime(); //timestamp, as you mentioned
var data = { 
    "property1": {".value": "updated_val", ".priority": newPriority},
    "property2": {".value": "updated_val2", ".priority": newPriority},
    ".priority": newPriority
}
ref.update(data);
```

Comment: Does `new Date()` get the client computer time? Then different users can have any time.

Comment: `new Date()` returns a new [Javascript Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), and `getTime()` is a method that returns ["the number of milliseconds since 1970/01/01"](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp). So, yes, this returns the client computer's time. If you want to use the server time, a special placeholder can be used to tell Firebase to auto-populate the current timestamp (time since the Unix epoch, in milliseconds) by the Firebase servers -- see [Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/servervalue/timestamp.html).